# Customer Registration on site redirecting wrong

Tags: registration, facebook-social-plugins, user-registration

I installed the registration application on my site - when it loaded, it looked fine, used my facebook as the trial registration customer, but when i hit the register button it opened a facebook allow page, all fine and dandy, but after that I was sent to a 404 page. Can anyone help me and tell me what i am doing wrong, I am brand new at this, as of today to be precise.
Thanks in anticipation
Dawn

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the javascript function with parameters like (d, s, id) and all meta property?Otherwise it'll not function properly. Long back I used the following code. It worked well.It opened facebook page for logging in.Here it is:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>    (function (d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


   <meta property="fb:admins" content="{urname@something.com}"/>
   <meta property="fb:title" content="ur title" />
   <meta property="fb:type" content="ur type of application" />
   <meta property="fb:url" content="http://www.yoururl" />
   <meta property="fb:image" content="" />
   <meta property="fb:site_name" content="Sitename" />
```

Hope you'll be able to change it according to your requirement.All the best.

Comment: ah I worked it out there was a & missing on the end of the address

Answer (score 0):

Probably a config setting issue with your app.  Double-Check the URLs you specify in your facebook app settings.